# Не собирается второе издание книги “Язык программирования Rust”

Tags: rust

В сеть выложили второе издание популярной книги “Язык программирования Rust” (https://github.com/ruRust/rust_book_2ed). Там же и инструкция, как собрать книжку из заготовок, с помощью *mdbook build*.  Однако - не получается! При выполнении этой команды вадаются сообщения:

```
(mdbook::utils): Error: Summary parsing failed
(mdbook::utils):    Caused By: There was an error parsing the numbered chapters
(mdbook::utils):    Caused By: Error at line 127, column 31: You can't have an empty link.
```

Я полный профан в Rust, для того и книжку пытаюсь получить - что бы прочитать. Может мне кто-то подсказать, в чём тут проблема?

Да, при первом запуске *mdbook build* выдалось длинное сообщение про то, что файл *book.toml* старого формата и его необходимо подправить. Я исправил, в соответствии с рекомендациями. Получилось вот так:

```
[book]
title = "The Rust Programming Language"
author = "Steve Klabnik and Carol Nichols, with Contributions from the Rust Community"

[build]
    [build-dir]
    destination = './build'
```

Comment: Сборка сейчас сломана, думаю починим в скором времени. Вообще с такими вопросами лучше писать сюда https://github.com/ruRust/rust_book_2ed/issues или в чат https://gitter.im/ruRust/rust_book_ru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Действительно не собирается. Но вопрос можно решить. Не собирается потому, что в файле `src/SUMMARY.md` не прописано несколько линков. Поступаем следующим образом:

1. В каталоге `src` создаем файл `dummy.md` примерного содержания

> `## Это файл-заглушка`
>
> `В документации не хватало пару файлов и книга не собиралась.`
>
> `Для этого делаем файл-заглушку.`

2. В файле `src/SUMMARY.md` в самом конце прописываем линки на этот файл

> `...`
>
> `- [Appendix](appendix-00.md)`
>
> `- [A - Keywords](appendix-01-keywords.md)`
>
> `- [B - Operators](appendix-02-operators.md)`
>
> `- [C - Derivable Traits](dummy.md)`
>
> `- [D - Nightly Rust](dummy.md)`
>
> `- [E - Macros](dummy.md)`
>
> `- [F - Translations](dummy.md)`
>
> `- [G - Newest Features](appendix-07-newest-features.md)`

Все, после этого сборка проходит нормально.

Comment: Действительно, собралась! Но, во время сборки (а это заняло минут 15 !!!) проц был занят на 100% и система почти не шевелилась :-(


Тогда вопрос номер два: а pdf можно сделать ? Я как-то привык больше с ними работать...

Comment: Ну и осталась проблема с англоязычным оглавлением... Откуда оно вообще берётся?!!

Comment: У меня собралось быстро, около 20 сек. Может от компа как-то сильно зависит ... А оглавление, скорее всего, тут править надо - `src/SUMMARY.md`.

Comment: По поводу PDF. На компе читать конечно удобно, но на планшете - не очень. Текст по словам не переносится, шрифт маленький. Пока конвертнул с CHM. Что интересно - на компе страшно глючит, а вот на плашете - все более-менее нормально.